# Go functions with mixed return/signature types

Tags: pointers, go

I'm trying to figure out how pointers work in Go and I think I'm starting to get it, but this is confusing me and I don't really know what to search for. Let's say I have the following function:

```
func createNode(nodeInfo string) *TreeNode {
    return &TreeNode{info: nodeInfo}
}
```

I understand that the function is returning the memory address of the created struct instance, but how does the function signature say `*TreeNode`? According to my understanding, the `*` is used to dereference pointers to get the value itself, so what is happening here?

Also, here:

```
 func zero(xPtr *int) {
  *xPtr = 0
}

func main() {
  x := 5
  zero(&x)
}
```

The opposite is happening where the function is accepting an argument with the `*` operator but the function itself is being called with `&` operator.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` has 2 uses, one for variables and one for types:

- For types, it signifies, that the type is a pointer, not a value directly.
- For variables, it dereferences a pointer, as you already know. (One might also distinguish this use into to two "sub-uses", as `*` on the left side of assignments, as in `*ptr = val` sets the value the pointer is pointing to, while `*` usually "retrieves" the value the pointer is pointing to.)

`&` on the other hand, can only be used for variables and gets the address of an object in memory.

In your examples, the return **type** `*TreeNode` and the argument **type** `*int` signify that you are returning/expecting a pointer, according to the use for *types*. In contrast, `*xPtr = 0` dereferences the **variable** `xPtr`.

To know which use is the correct one in your situation, you must make clear to yourself whether you are dealing with a type or a variable.

For a technical description, you can read the sections of the [language specifications](https://golang.org/ref/spec) on [Pointer types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) and [Address operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators).

Comment: I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around that first one with the types. Is the purpose of this to just say "this is pointing to an object with this specific type"?

Comment: Yes, that is all it does. Prefixing a type expression with `*` is just the syntax used to say that in Go (and other languages as well).